# Error Message while sending the SQL mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Error message:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2020-12-19T11:03:17). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.4.2 Message submission rate for this client has exceeded the configured limit).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message clearly says what's wrong:

```
4.4.2 Message submission rate for this client has exceeded the configured limit
```

Possible solutions:

- raise the configured limit of the targeted smtp server
- use an other smpt server

Comment: But the limit was not exceeded ,only two mail was delivered to the client !

Comment: Sql server writes in the `The server response was:` part what it gets from the smtp server, there's no interpretation in between. Double check configurations on sql and smtp server, smtp log might give some useful hints, too.